# Workgroup Logon

Tags: windows-xp, login, user, workgroup

I have a two XP SP3 PC's in a LAN which:

- Are on their own Workgroups.
- Have NetBIOS over TCP/IP enabled.
- Have the windows (or 3rd party) firewall disabled.
- Have file and printer sharing installed and enabled.
- Have simple file sharing disabled.
- Have dynamic IPs, I've tried with static IPs but it causes Workgroup
  authentication problems.
- Have the computer browser service set to automatic and started.
- Have the same OS, freshly installed.
- Can all ping each other fine.
- Have no Primary DNS Suffix.
- Have no Private Host names.
- Have the same Usernames and passwords.
- Have the same Account SID's.
- Have identical Group Policy Configurations
- Can view each others workgroups and shared folders in My Network Places

I am entering the username on the PC: 'XP2' as: XP1\Administrator, and then the password but it just logs on locally as XP2\Administrator, any ideas why?

Do I need to forward the DNS server for XP2 to XP1 or do something with WINS? I'm quite lost here How do I login to the other PC.

If they were both in the same Workgroup it will still fail at this stage but may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

User accounts are not shared between workstations, not even within a workgroup. Either they're *domain* accounts, or local to the machine. (So Windows ignores the `XP1\` part in order to make network logins work seamlessly. When you access XP2's files from XP1, you are really logging in to XP2's *local* account with the same name as yours.)

(This has nothing to do with DNS, WINS, nor account SIDs.)

You can create a domain through Windows Server, or using Samba on a Linux system. (Samba 4 can create Active Directory domains; Samba 3 only supports the older NT4 domains.)

Comment: but roaming profiles, remote desktop / terminal services can do this on a workgroup. roaming profile requires the profile to point to the network drive however prior to logging on remotley

Comment: That's wrong on several counts. Roaming profiles _are not_ Remote Desktop. They're not even remotely similar to Remote Desktop. And Remote Desktop doesn't do account sharing either. If you RDP into XP2, you will still need to use XP2's accounts to log in.

Comment: roaming profile can (on a wordgroup) logon to another PC who's profile path is set to the remote PC, however that is on the same workgroup the username is entered just as 'username' in the logon window rather than as a logon path.

Comment: ok, and that's _not_ the same as what you're asking for – you aren't actually using a remote account this way, you're just manually configuring certain things to be stored on a network share.

Comment: The user profile is the network share so it IS a remote profile only stored on the host but the user account is stored on both PC's. Eg (\\HostIP\C:\Documents and Settings\MyProfile$)